# How to mount hostpath on a pod with podname as a subdirectory

Tags: kubernetes

I have a use-case where I need to mount a `hostpath` to a pod but that `hostpath should have a subdirectory with PODNAME`, I know something like this can be used with statefulsets but due to some constraints a hostpath mount is needed in deployment where the root directory will have sub directories as `podnames`.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: I'd normally expect a Deployment-managed Pod to have a unique name, and a `hostPath` volume will point at different storage depending on the node the Pod happens to run on.  If every pod will have unique, non-recoverable storage, can you use an `emptyDir:` volume instead?

Comment: @DavidMaze No emptyDir is not an option, it will get lost

Comment: `hostPath` volumes will get lost too, if your pod runs on a different node, and the requirement to use a directory matching the unique pod name seems to mean the volume will never get reused in any case.

Comment: @DavidMaze it's alright, In my case the hostpath is an EBS which will contain logs, so we just need a space to keep app logs based on pods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **[downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/downward-api/)** of Kubernetes as [Environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/) :

```
- name: pod_name
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
            apiVersion: v1
            fieldPath: metadata.name
```

Feel free to refer my GitHub YAML : https://github.com/harsh4870/OCI-public-logging-uma-agent/blob/main/deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: app
    image: <App image>
    env:
      - name: pod_name
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
            apiVersion: v1
            fieldPath: metadata.name
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /app_logs
      name: app-logs
      subPathExpr: $(pod_name)
  volumes:
  - name: mydir
    hostPath:
      path: /var/log/app_logs
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

Here is full article i have used **downwardAPI** for logging : https://medium.com/@harsh.manvar111/oke-logging-with-uma-agent-in-oci-d6f55a8bcc02

Comment: looks promising, thanks I will check and update you soon

Comment: sure, no issues..!